# Time tracking when status is changed

Tags: siebel, escript

I have a question about a specific functionality in Siebel, regarding service requests.

Is there a way to track time when certain service request is in a given status/substatus, for example "Waiting on Customer"? When the service request is changed again to another status that isn't "Wait for somebody" anymore, I have to stop counting the time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any *out of the box* solution to your needs, however there are many ways to achieve it with a bit of customisation. For example:

1. Create two new fields, `Waiting Time` (with predefault value: 0) and `Waiting Date`.
2. Create the following BC user properties:

   - `On Field Update Set x` = `"Status", "Waiting Time", "IIF([Waiting Date] IS NULL, [Waiting Time], [Waiting Time] + (Timestamp() - [Waiting Date]))`
   - `On Field Update Set y` = `"Status", "Waiting Date", "IIF([Status]='Waiting on Customer',Timestamp(),NULL)"`

Your `Waiting Date` field will store the last time the service request changed to "Waiting on Customer", or NULL if it's on another status. Then, `Waiting Time` will accumulate the total time the request has been in that status.

I have not tested the solution, it might need some more work, for example, it's possible that Siebel doesn't allow you to use the expression `[Waiting Time] + (Timestamp() - [Waiting Date])` directly and you'll have to decompose it using auxiliary calculated fields.

Note also that the On Field Update Set user property has changed its syntax from [Siebel 7.7-7.8](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E05553_01/books/ToolsDevRef/ToolsDevRef_UserProps124.html) to [Siebel 8.x](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/ToolsDevRef/ToolsDevRef_UserProps102.html).

If you're familiar with server scripting, you could implement something similar quite easily, on the `BusComp_PreSetFieldValue` event. If the field being changed is Status, check if you're entering or exiting (or not) the "Waiting on Customer" status, and update the two fields accordingly.